# 'Do you accept the terms and conditions?' on Log In Forms Authentication MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, dialog

I'm struggling with having a login dialog box appear on login. What I need to happen is when the user logs in using the built in MVC3 authentication controls, I need it to pop up a dialog that spits out some terms and agreements, and says "if you hit accept, you agree to the above". I currently have that, but when I hit cancel, the site will still log in anyway. Here is my code:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userName)
        </div>
        <div class="focus">
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.passWord)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.passWord)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="btnLogin" id="btnLogin" />
        </p>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


</fieldset>
```

And the Javascript that I have:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
                var answer = confirm("Unauthorized access or use of the web content is prohibited.\n" + "By clicking 'OK', you have agreed to the above conditions");
                if (answer) {
                }
                else {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How would I get it to just cancel the HttpPost on login when the user hits cancel on the dialog and continue to login if they hit ok?

Much appreciated!!

Comment: Just so you know, someone can still get by your login without checking that because you are only checking that value on the client. You should validate all input no matter what it is from the client and the server both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your event handler add this

```
 $("#btnLogin").click(function (event) {
     var answer = confirm("Unauthorized access or use of the web content is prohibited.\n" + "By clicking 'OK', you have agreed to the above conditions");
     if (answer) {

     }
     else{
          $(this).dialog("close");
          event.preventDefault();
     }
 });
```

Adding the  `event.preventDefault();` you're ensuring preveting the default behavior of the form

Comment: This only helps client side and will not help for server side validation

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! I can't upvote you until I earn 15 reputations, but I will hit the check as soon as I can (it says I need to wait 5 minutes)

Comment: @CDSmith it's correct, but in the question don't specify if need server or client side, but you answer is valid too, for server side

Comment: @Jorge yes I agree yours is also correct, just trying to protect the user's site against anyone that knows that if they post without the form then the site will still let them in

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that this is validated server side as well as client side use this technique, works perfect. If you rely on only javascript someone can still log into your by getting around that.

Add a new `bool` property called `AcceptTerms` to your model

```
[Display(Name = "Accept Terms and Conditions")]
[IsTrue]
public bool AcceptTerms { get; set; }
```

In your view

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AcceptTerms) </br>
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.AcceptTerms) </br>
@Html.ValidationFor(model => model.AcceptTerms)
```

Create a new attribute so that you can verify that it is checked

```
public class IsTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidOperationException("can only be used on boolean properties.");

        return (bool) value == true;
    }
}
```